# Two concurrent statements writing to database

Tags: postgresql, transactions

```
+---+---------+-----------+
|id |  title  |description| 
+---+---------------------+
| 1 | The King|  Jonh X   |
+---+---------------------+
```

Two **concurrent** statements:

```
update book set title = 'aaa', description = 'aaa' where id = 1

update book set title = 'bbb', description = 'bbb' where id = 1
```

Is it **theoretically** possible the following result?

```
+---+---------+-----------+
|id |  title  |description| 
+---+---------------------+
| 1 |   aaa   |   bbbb    |
+---+---------------------+
```

```
update book set title = 'aaa', description = 'aaa' where id = 1

select title, description from book -> (The King, aaa)?
```

Those statements are not wrapped in transaction

What about popular database systems like SQL Server, Postgres?

Comment: No it is not theoretically possible. Update statements may seem concurrent but they do not in fact run at the same time. This would violate the ACID principles.

Comment: The I in ACID stands for Isolation. Meaning you cannot run two queries in parallel.

Comment: If those statements are not "wrapped" in a transaction, then they run with "autocommit" enabled. Which means the change is committed as soon as the statement is finished. So each update is a single transaction. Both updates are run in _some_ order. So the outcome you have shown is not possible in any modern DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Generally impossible** in any **ACID**-compliant database.
ACID stands for ***atomicity, consistency, isolation, durability***.

In particular, Postgres takes a write-lock on affected rows before the `UPDATE` and does not release it until the end of the transaction. (And *every* `UPDATE` runs inside a transaction, implicitly or explicitly.) Concurrent transactions trying to write to the same row must wait and re-evaluate filters once the lock is released. They may then change the row once more - or come up empty if the filters do not apply any more.

Comment: I was convinced that ACID relates to only transactions. It relates to databases generally?

Comment: @J.Doe: ACID does related to transactions, and you can **not** run a statement without a transaction.

Comment: That's what Erwin meant by _implicit_ `UPDATE`